# I Extracted coordinates of character from pdf but I want to display rectangular box on character and display pdf

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, ocr, pdfminer

I tried this code but not able to locate box on it I am using google colab. I want to detect text from pdf with its coordinates.

'''

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
fp = open(pathh, 'rb')
pathh="/content/drive/MyDrive/ICAO.pdf"
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
pages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp)

for page in pages:
    print('Processing next page...')
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    for lobj in layout:
        if isinstance(lobj, LTTextBox):
            x, y, text = lobj.bbox[0], lobj.bbox[3], lobj.get_text()
            print('At %r is text: %s' % ((x, y), text))
```

'''

Comment: okay and what's preventing you from doing what you want?

Comment: please provide atleast your current code and walk us step by step on what it does and end on where you have issues.

Comment: I want to process airport diagram which is in pdf format. Using above code I get coordinates of particular text which is present on airport diagram. My question is how we can add box over text and print updated pdf.

Comment: This is pdf of airport diagram https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fjJggUGhSF9CurEf1IjAoYhOnRslx8ew/view?usp=sharing

Comment: After processing I want output in these form                                                              https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FYSAo6XFVpH9jiBeSKB2y9k51ATEMxF7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you clear @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: Are you clear @ColdCerberus